# Blue screen of death

Tags: windows-7, boot, updates

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. Windows will load, and I get to the desktop. But after it shows all the icons I get the BSOD. The message is "page fault in non page area". Never heard of this error. It happened after I downloaded updates from Microsoft. I can boot into Safe Mode, but not regular mode. I can't even do a image restore with Aronis True Image, even older images. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Once in safe mode, can you restore using the regular windows restore points?

Comment: @MaxMackie please watch the language.

Comment: If you're booting into Safe Mode successfully, the problem appears to be a faulty driver. There are several related questions on this forum that will help you navigate the minefield of disabling services and re-enabling them one by one to identify the culprit.

Comment: Is the Acronis image a full system image? Have you replaced any hardware since the image was made? If a full system image does not work on identical hardware then that would suggest a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Turned out to be a software conflick between two similar programs. Uninstalled one of them, problem solved.

Comment: please answer your question with software names so that it will be of use to others..

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments [by OP](https://superuser.com/questions/285042/blue-screen-of-death/1729383#comment299959_285042).

> Turned out to be a software conflic[t] between two similar programs. Uninstalled one of them, problem solved.